# Java array problem. Cant pass values

Tags: java

Wen I have this code:

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
    import java.util.Arrays;
    public class Ex02 {

        /**
         * @param args the command line arguments
         */
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            int [] matrixSize = new int [4];
            System.out.println("Insert the values matrix (matrixA_lines,MatrixA_Rows,matrixB_lines,MatrixB_Rows");
            matrixSize = matrixFill(4);
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(matrixSize));
        }

        public static int[] matrixFill(int sizeOne){
            int i;
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

            int [] matrixTemp = new int [sizeOne];
            for (i = 0; i<sizeOne; i++){
                matrixTemp[i] = sc.nextInt();
            }

            return matrixTemp;
        }
    }
```

It all works as expected. An unidimensional array is created, filled with 1,2,3,4 and them the array is print. The problem is that i want to use an bidimentsional array. I've modified the code and it gives error.
Here is the modified code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;
public class Ex02 {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int [][] matrixSize = new int [1][4];
        System.out.println("Insert the values matrix (matrixA_lines,MatrixA_Rows,matrixB_lines,MatrixB_Rows");
        matrixSize[][] = matrixFill(1,4);
        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(matrixSize));
    }

    public static int[][] matrixFill(int sizeOne, int sizeTwo){
        int i;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        int [][] matrixTemp = new int [sizeOne][sizeTwo];
        for (i = 0; i<sizeOne; i++){
            matrixTemp[0][i] = sc.nextInt();
        }

        return matrixTemp[sizeOne][sizeTwo];
    }
}
```

On line 21 (matrixSize[][] = matrixFill(1,4);) the error is:

```
cannot find symbol
symbol:   class matrixSize
location: class Ex02.Ex02

not a statement

';' expected
```

And on line 34(return matrixTemp[sizeOne][sizeTwo];) the error is:

```
incompatible types
required: int[][]
found:    int
```

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Just started to learn Java.

Regards,

favolas

Comment: The return statement 'return matrixTemp[sizeOne][sizeTwo]' is returning the object found at [sizeOne][sizeTwo] and so it fails since the object found there is only a int, since you declare that the method should return something that is int[][]. 'return matrixTemp' will do fine there.

Comment: The first error, you should only put matrixSize = matrixFill(1,4) since you already declared what matrixSize is.

Comment: Thanks AntonioP. As you explained it was easy to understand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `[][]` from matrixSize, and from your return value.

```
matrixSize = matrixFill(1,4);
```

And

```
return matrixTemp;
```

Comment: Just a note... I don't have line numbers on the code you provided, but I'll bet they're 21 and 34. Just saying, those compilation errors will help you a lot. Learning to read your tools' outputs will help you be a better programmer. Forever. :)

Comment: Hi there. I've stated that the errors were on those lines. Even with the compilation errors I wasn't getting it right.

Answer (score 0):

```
matrixSize[][] = matrixFill(1,4);
```

That's not a valid place for the `[][]`. The first example had it right:

```
matrixSize = matrixFill(1,4);
```

Answer (score 0):

You added "[sizeOne][sizeTwo]" to the return statement in the new code; you do not need this because matrixTemp has already been declared as a 2d array.  The way you changed it, you are sending one element within the array.